# Loading animated GIFs from resource file in wxWidgets

Tags: image, wxwidgets, gif

I am trying to embed an animated GIF image into a wxWidgets C++ program. I am able to load the image from file and display it like so:

```
wxAnimationCtrl *an = new wxAnimationCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxAnimation(wxT("image.gif"), wxANIMATION_TYPE_ANY), wxPoint(150,0));
an->Play();
```

But I would rather have the GIF image in my resource.rc file, so that it is compiled into the executable. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [wxMSWResources](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/showcomp.php?name=wxMSWResources) or [wxLoadUserResource](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_miscellany.html#wxloaduserresource) function, load GIF resource to memory, then obtain [wxMemoryInputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_memory_input_stream.html) and then use [wxAnimation::Load()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_animation.html#a6434b9dcc63295b0e393a21a59eb634) and pass that input stream to that function

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
m_ani = new wxAnimationCtrl();
const void* data = NULL;
size_t outLen = 0;

// load the icon directory resource
if ( !wxLoadUserResource(&data, &outLen, "ID_WAIT", RT_RCDATA) )
{
    wxLogError(_("Failed to load icons from resource"));
}
else
{
    wxMemoryInputStream stream(data, outLen);
    if (m_ani->Load(stream))  m_ani->Play();
}
```